# Bonjour and Apple Network Framework in hotels

Tags: ios, swift, networking, bonjour, network-framework

I got a client server app that uses Bonjour and Apple Network framework with UDP.

The app doesn't work in hotel rooms however as hotels seem to be blocking either Bonjour or UDP or both.

Any idea if and how this limitation might by bypassed. I need to enable my users to use the app on the road. Bluetooth would definitely by an option but I really like the network framework so maybe one of you has an idea.

Thomas